# Atomic write on writeshared opened file

Tags: c#, filestream, atomic

I have a file stream opened in writeshare and append mode from multiple processes.
Does anybody know if a single unbuffered write operation can be considered atomic?

Or have i to develop a way to synchronize different writes to ensure my data are safe?

Comment: No - you need to implement proper synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my way.

You can open a filestream using this constructor.

```
new FileStream(FileName,
    FileMode.Append,
    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.AppendData,
    FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, FileOptions.None);
```

using **System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.AppendData** parameter to open the stream, with **FileMode.Append**, the OS will try to write the buffer in atomic way.

If your write is bigger than buffer size, the operation will not be atomic, so you have to check your buffer size.

Comment: Can you add a source for your statement that this is atomic, depending on the buffer size?

Comment: Apparently FileSystemRights is not in dotnetstandard 2.0.